# Complicated array merging (keeping order)

Tags: javascript

I've got two arrays as follows:

```
const array1 = [
  {
    id: 'a1',
    text: 'some text'
  },
  {
    id: 'a2',
    text: 'some more text',
  },
  {
    id: 'a3',
    text: 'some more text',
  },
]
```

and

```
const array2 = [
  {
    id: 'a1',
    text: 'some text' 
  },
  {
    id: 'ab12',
    text: 'some text' 
  },
  {
    id: 'abc123',
    text: 'some further text'
  },
  {
    id: 'a3',
    text: 'some more text' 
  },
  {
    id: 'bx44',
    text: 'some more text' 
  },
]
```

I would like to combine these arrays with information has to whether each item has a "matching" 'id' property as the other array, so:

```
combined = [
  {
    id: 'a1',
    text: 'some text',
    info: 'in-both'
  },
  {
    id: 'a2',
    text: 'some text',
    info: 'only-array1',
  },
  {
    id: 'ab12',
    text: 'some text',
    info: 'only-array2',
  },
  {
    id: 'abc123',
    text: 'some further text',
    info: 'only-array2',
  },
  {
    id: 'a3',
    text: 'some more text',
    info: 'in-both',
  },
  {
    id: 'bx44',
    text: 'some more text',
    info: 'only-array2',
  },
]
```

I'm trying to keep the "inherent" order, so that items being only present in array1 or array2 end up between matches (items in both arrays) relative to their index. For example, 'a2' (only present in array1) comes after 'a1' but before 'a3'. If, between matches, there are multiple items being present only in array1 or array2, I'm trying to achieve so that the ones belonging to array1 come first (in the example, 'a2' comes before 'ab12' and 'abc123').

The code so far:

```
array1.reduce((all, curr, a1index, a1array) => {
  let correspondingItemInArray2Index = array2.findIndex(a2item => a2item.id === curr.id);
  if(correspondingItemInArray2Index === -1) {
    curr.info = 'only-in-array1';
  }
  else if(correspondingItemInArray2Index === a1index) {
    // Items are on same level...
    curr.info = 'in-both';
  }
  else {
    ... // I need to find all items of array2 until the next 'match' of ids?
  }

}
, []);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get common items and iterate all between.

```js
function merge(...data) {
    var common = data.map(a => a.map(({ id }) => id)).reduce((a, b) => a.filter(v => b.includes(v))),
        indices = data.map(_ => 0),
        result = [];

    while (indices.every((l, i) => l < data[i].length)) {
        indices = indices.map((j, i) => {
            while (j < data[i].length && !common.includes(data[i][j].id)) {
                result.push(Object.assign({}, data[i][j++], { info: ['a', 'b'][i] }));
            }
            return j;
        });
        if (indices.some((l, i) => l >= data[i].length)) break;
        result.push(Object.assign({}, data[0][indices[0]], { info: 'both' }));
        indices = indices.map(v => v + 1);
    }
    indices.forEach((j, i) => {
        while (j < data[i].length) {
            result.push(Object.assign({}, data[i][j++], { info: ['a', 'b'][i] }));
        }
    });
    return result;
}


var array1 = [{ id: 'a1', text: 'some text' }, { id: 'a2', text: 'some more text' }, { id: 'a3', text: 'some more text' }],
    array2 = [{ id: 'a1', text: 'some text' }, { id: 'ab12', text: 'some text' }, { id: 'abc123', text: 'some further text' }, { id: 'a3', text: 'some more text' }, { id: 'bx44', text: 'some more text' }],
    result = merge(array1, array2);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you! Follow up question, when adding the 'both' item, is there an easy way to access the other match? Or would I have to go search the whole array2 by id?

Comment: you have the index in `indices` which points to a common element.

Comment: Thanks. Seems to be located at data[1][indicies[1]]